# Problem with getting data from server - RN

Tags: android, react-native, server, dns, vps

I'm building my first mobile app using React Native. Let's say that will be something like Spotify. I'm getting songs data from Firestore, for example title, author, duration, description and link to the song which is located on my own server.
When I try to connect by domain address I can't get anything. While I'm using an IP address my app works fine only in debug mode - in release mode nothing. What can I do to repair that?

Comment: Could you post some code so it'd be easier to spot the actual problem?

Comment: @SamuliHakoniemi what exactly you want to see ?

Comment: _" When I try to connect by domain address I can't get anything"_ --> how do you try to connect?

Comment: @SamuliHakoniemi for example something like that: <Image source={{ uri: https://www.someexamplelink.com/someexampleimage }} />
I noticed that if SSL is turned on then image won't appear either in debug or release mode. If SSL is turned off image will appear only in debug mode.